# I want to store the characters in image. swift

Tags: swift, image, text

I want to store the text in image.

I want to store text inside the image. 
Is this possible? For example, the image contains various information such as location information. 
I like to store my text inside the images like them.

I want to store the string inside the data of the image rather than the visual.

For example, you might want to store a small string that identifies the image in the image, so you want to separate it when you import the image.

I want to implement it in swift.

Comment: You can do it by manipulating its pixels by ordinal(or ASCII) values of letters of the text you wanna write.

Comment: QR codes? And your statement `It is not a string in image` doesn't make sense. Text is a string in code.

Comment: I want to store the string inside the data of the image rather than the visual.
For example, you might want to store a small string that identifies the image in the image, so you want to separate it when you import the image.

Comment: What do you mean by "image?" Do you mean a `UIImage`, or an image file, or something else? It sounds like you want to store text as metadata in an image. You can do this with image _files_ in some formats (e.g. jpeg, tiff). But you haven't specified the type of image, so I don't know if this matches your use case.

Comment: Yes. I want to take a photo with the iPhone and save it in the camera roll and insert some text inside the photo file. Its file format is jpg. It's probably the meta information that's referring to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Q still leaks of information, what you really want to do. But I'll try to give you an answer, which might be a step to a better Q.

If you are talking about "inside" the image, you might mean inside the pixel data itself. It is possible to add data to an image without changing the image for humans. This is called a digital watermark or fingerprint. Typically this is used for DRM. You will find some information about this by using a search machine like Qwant.

But I do not think, that you really want to do this. Likely you want to add information in an image file. First of all you need a file format supporting additional data. Tiff is an example. AFAIK there is no build-in facility to get partial TIFF data for the image with ability to add private tasks. You have to create the file your own.

Comment: I wanted to store some little text inside the image as if it contained location information inside the image.  I did not know it was so complicated that I had to create a new format of file. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to google for „EXIF“. That‘s the name of the standard for storing metadata in JPEG files. There may be a standard field in that standard in which you can store your data, or it might even define how to add your own types. However, Apple‘s libraries might only support the most common field types (you may want to verify that... maybe ImageIO has something for you). So you may have to find a 3rd party JPEG or EXIF library to be able to add your metadata.

Comment: Indeed, exif is the better idea.

Comment: You are right. It looks like you should use EXIF. Thank you.